# JDBC Thin Connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have installed NetBeans 6.5 with JDK1.6. And I want to connect between oracle with java in NetBeans 6.5. The question is:

How do I configure JDBC to java 1.6?

Thanks,
Sopolin

Answer (score 4):

[Download page for Oracle JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html) and [Oracle JDBC examples](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/index.html). Also see Sun's [JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the Oracle thin JDBC driver and pop it on your classpath.

See this for a code example.

http://w2.syronex.com/jmr/edu/db/oracle-and-java

Comment: Hi, I saw your reference but after I follow the example in this web site, I have the error occurs. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C:\TestJava\DbTest
Cause by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: c:\TestJava\DbTest
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source).....
Could you guide me to configure JDBC Thin driver in oracle with java?

Comment: How are you executing your program it looks like your doing something wrong. It should look something like java -cp ... DbTest what IDE are you using as it's easier to run and configure apps through an IDE.

Comment: Yes, I copied DbTest to run for testing already. Then when I ran it, it appears this error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the hints: 
1.download the proper ORACLE DB driver version from following sites:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html
and import into the libary of Netbeans if you use NETBEANS as IDE.

2.In your Java code, define appropriate JDBC connections statement like that:

```
    public static final String DBDRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" ;
public static final String DBURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:Your_DB_NAME";
public static final String DBUSER = "YOUR ORACLE DB ID" ;
public static final String DBPASS = "YOUR ORACLE DB PASSWORD" ;


Connection conn = null ;    // DB CONNECTIONS
PreparedStatement pstmt = null ;//  DB  OPERATIONS
ResultSet rs = null ;       //  save the query result


Class.forName(DBDRIVER) ;   // Load the ORACLE DRIVER
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL,DBUSER,DBPASS) ;
String sql = "SELECT name FROM client" ;   //sample query
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql) ;   // execute the query and save the result

   // the above cope snippet is the main things of JDBC.
   //Hope it helps!
```